# How to iterate over positional script parameters in sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

In an Oracle sqlplus script, I can use single script parameters as

```
set serveroutput on
define arg = '&1'
begin
    dbms_output.putline('&arg.');
end;
/
```

And in a Unix shell, I can iterate over given script arguments and pass that to an sqlplus script with

```
for x in "$@"; do
    sqlplus user/passwd@sid @script.sql "$x"
done
```

---

Is there a similar way in Oracle sqlplus? Something like

```
for arg in &* loop
    dbms_output.putline('&arg.');
end loop;
```

where `arg` would take values of `&1`, `&2`, `&3`, ...
This means, when I call

```
$ sqlplus user/passwd@sid @script.sql a b c
```

I would see as output

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: you can do this using PL/SQL inside sqlplus. Is it ok for you ??

Comment: I don't understand, but if there's a way, I would be interested.

Comment: Just to be clear. The list of arguments might contain any number of variables , and they are split by a whitespace . Am I correct ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I updated the question, maybe it's clearer now.

Comment: I post an answer. Let me know if it covers what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if this is what you are looking for.

1. We have an undetermined list of parameters
2. All of them are split by whitespace ( as it were a list on bash input parameters )
3. Do something with all of them, independently of the number of parameters
4. In order for `sqlplus` to deal with this, all of the parameters must be enclosed with double quotes, so that the code will interpret them as only one parameter.

**Script**

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited
declare
vstring  varchar2(4000) := '&1';
vcounter pls_integer;
vrecord  varchar2(20);
BEGIN
vcounter := regexp_count( vstring , ' ') + 1;
for var in 1..vcounter 
loop
    if var = 1 
    then
        vrecord := regexp_substr( vstring, '[^ ]+', 1 , 1 );
        dbms_output.put_line(vrecord);
    elsif var > 1 and var <= vcounter 
    then 
        vrecord := regexp_substr( vstring, '[^ ]+', 1 , var );
        dbms_output.put_line(vrecord); 
    end if;
end loop;   
end;
/
```

I have this script stored as iteration.sql. So, let's run it with a set of parameters

```
SQL>  @iteration.sql "2"
old   2: vstring  varchar2(4000) := '&1';
new   2: vstring  varchar2(4000) := '2';
2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> @iteration.sql "2 m3 88 99 ajkd8 0 88 aa"
old   2: vstring  varchar2(4000) := '&1';
new   2: vstring  varchar2(4000) := '2 m3 88 99 ajkd8 0 88 aa';
2
m3
88
99
ajkd8
0
88
aa

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Ok, this is a manual approach, but not really what I expected. Sorry for being not clear enough upfront.

Comment: @"Olaf Dietsche" , can you put a real example ? It is not very clear to me what you are expecting. You have a set of variable input parameters. Where are they coming from ??  are they always 3 or can be 1 or 2 or n ? your script runs with three or more input parameters and you want a line for each one ?

Comment: Printing the parameters is just an example, this could be any function or procedure to call with this parameter. And this could be any number of parameters, not just three. Sometimes it's just one parameter, sometimes many more.